# Show instance of component within a ngFor

Tags: angular

I cannot be able to change the instance of a component within a **ngFor** for lack of knowledge.

```
<div  *ngFor="let xen of xens; let idx = index">
     <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="button" (click)="app-xeneditor.Hide==true" value="Edit Xen">
     </div>
     <app-xeneditor [Xen]="xen" [Hide]="true"></app-xeneditor>
</div>
```

When i click on Edit Xen button, i expect to show the editor that row only.  I have no clear idea how to update the parameter of component app-xeneditor within the ngFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the editor state in an array.

```
public isEditorVisible: boolean[] = [];
```

It might be necessary to initialize this array with as many items as in `xens`, all set to false. Make sure to do so when `xens` is available.

Now in the template, have the `input` element call a method that will set the visibility flags appropriately, and use `ngIf` to control the visibility of the `app-xeneditor` element.

```
<div *ngFor="let xen of xens; let idx = index">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="button" (click)="showEditor(idx)" value="Edit Xen">
  </div>
  <app-xeneditor *ngIf="isEditorVisible[idx]" [Xen]="xen"></app-xeneditor>
</div>
```

Then define method `showEditor` to look something like this:

```
public showEditor(idx: number): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < xens.length; i++) {
    isEditorVisible[i] = (i === idx);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HI can you define in your component

```
bool_var:boolean =false
```

then your html file

```
<div  *ngFor="let xen of xens; let idx = index">
     <div class="col-md-2">
         <input type="button" (click)="bool_var=true" value="Edit Xen">
     </div>
     <app-xeneditor [Xen]="xen" [Hide]="bool_var"></app-xeneditor>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work, this shows the editor for every row, not just the row i click the button on.

Comment: Hi you can add extra key "bool_var" set false ,then assign that key [Hide]="xen.bool_var",then you click that button change that key value

Comment: I though of adding an extra key to the collection item but thought their was a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Try to avoid hidding components, use structural directives instead like `*ngIf` because if you hide something, it will be there and will spend resources just because it's there, with a structural directive you will remove the component from the DOM.